# Pasting QMimeData to another window's QTextEdit

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I'm still quite a newbie with Python and PyQt so I have a really basic question. I have some text and images in a parent window inside a QTextEdit widget and I'm trying to copy all the content to a child window's QTextEdit. But for some reason I can't get it to copy the image - only the text is copied not the image. Here's a snippet of the code that's giving me trouble:

```
self.textEdit.selectAll()
data = self.textEdit.createMimeDataFromSelection()
self.child_window.textEdit.insertFromMimeData(data) # doesn't work with images
```

Here's is the small program that I'm trying to run:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MyWindow,self).__init__(parent)

        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.textEdit.setText("Hello World\n")

        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton.setText("Copy and paste to Child Window")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.click_copy_data)

        self.pushButton2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton2.setText("Insert Image")
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.click_file_dialog)

        self.layoutVertical = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButton2)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.setGeometry(150, 150,640, 480)
        self.child_window = CustomWindow(self)
        self.child_window.show()

    def click_copy_data(self):

        self.textEdit.selectAll()
        data = self.textEdit.createMimeDataFromSelection()
        self.child_window.textEdit.insertFromMimeData(data)

    def click_file_dialog(self):
        filePath = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self,
            "Select an image",
            ".",
            "Image Files(*.png *.gif *.jpg *jpeg *.bmp)"
        )

        if not filePath.isEmpty():
            self.insertImage(filePath)


    def insertImage(self,filePath):

        imageUri = QtCore.QUrl(QtCore.QString("file://{0}".format(filePath)))
        image    = QtGui.QImage(QtGui.QImageReader(filePath).read())

        self.textEdit.document().addResource(
            QtGui.QTextDocument.ImageResource,
            imageUri,
            QtCore.QVariant(image)
        )

        imageFormat = QtGui.QTextImageFormat()
        imageFormat.setWidth(image.width())
        imageFormat.setHeight(image.height())
        imageFormat.setName(imageUri.toString())

        textCursor = self.textEdit.textCursor()
        textCursor.movePosition(
            QtGui.QTextCursor.End,
            QtGui.QTextCursor.MoveAnchor
        )
        textCursor.insertImage(imageFormat)

        # This will hide the cursor
        blankCursor = QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.BlankCursor)
        self.textEdit.setCursor(blankCursor)

class CustomWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(CustomWindow,self).__init__(parent)

        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)

        self.layoutVertical = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.textEdit)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')
    main = MyWindow()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The way the program works is that you have some text inside the main window and then you insert an image. Then you click "Copy and paste to Child Window" button and it should paste all the contents to the child, including the image - but that doesn't work that way it's supposed to - the text is copied but I get a little file icon where the image should be.

I would appreciate your help on this.

Paul

Answer (score 1):

`QTextEdit` doesn't decode image MIME types by default, so just subclass it to add support, you'll need to reimplement [`canInsertFromMimeData`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtextedit.html#canInsertFromMimeData) and [`insertFromMimeData`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtextedit.html#insertFromMimeData), also try [`QTextBrowser`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtextbrowser.html) instead. Just add this to your script:

```
class MyTextBrowser(QtGui.QTextBrowser):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTextBrowser, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setReadOnly(False)

    def canInsertFromMimeData(self, source):
        if source.hasImage():
            return True

        else:
            return super(MyTextBrowser, self).canInsertFromMimeData(source)

    def insertFromMimeData(self, source):
        if source.hasImage():
            image = QtCore.QVariant(source.imageData())

            document = self.document()
            document.addResource(
                QtGui.QTextDocument.ImageResource,
                QtCore.QUrl("image"),
                image
            )

            cursor = self.textCursor()
            cursor.insertImage("image")

        super(MyTextBrowser, self).insertFromMimeData(source)
```

And change `self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)` into `self.textEdit = MyTextBrowser(self)` on both widgets.

Comment: This is strange. For some reason source.hasImage() doesn't return True. Even when I try a .jpg or .png file.

Comment: this is what I tried:  print "has image?", data.hasImage(). I get False.

Comment: That's because an html MIME type is being used, it is kind like if you where saying `mimedata = textEdit.toHtml()` and `textEdit.setHtml(mimedata)`

Comment: Sorry but how can I implement the behavior of copying text AND images inside QTextEdit field using QMimeData? I am still a newb so I don't fully quite understand the documentation.

Comment: I hope I don't have to reimplement createMimeDataFromSelection(). That's too advanced for me. :'(

Comment: That's exactly what you are doing, using an html MIME type. If you want to use a different MIME type you'll have to implement it yourself, possibly iterating over the elements on your document and checking their types. Note that `QMimeData` is usually used to supply data to the `QDrag` or `QClipboard` objects,  using the `toHtml` method would be much more convenient in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I ended using as suggested by X.Jacobs.

```
html = parent_textEdit.toHtml()
child_textEdit.setHtml(html)
```

I was making things more complicated. When I realized that QTextEdit keeps track of where the image is stored as a url inside the html generated by toHtml() then it all made sense.